# Can I bring 10-20 Hot Wheels in the packaging on a plane WITHOUT the intent to sell?

Tags: customs

I am a Hot Wheels collector and am moving to a new country. I have to ship most of my collection a couple of months before I actually move. Being a collector, I will probably buy 10 or so before the day I fly over. I heard that you need a business license if you are bringing over many of the same kind of product in its packaging so I am just wondering either how many I can bring with me as a “personal belonging” or if I just declare them “collector items” and not having the intention to sell if I’ll be ok.

Comment: What country are you moving to?

Comment: Is this 10 exact copies or 10 different designs/models?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What research have you done up to now? Personally I doubt *an airline* will care. But if you want to know about Customs restrictions you will have to state the country you’re moving to. An indication of the value of the items might also be helpful.

Comment: This belongs on [Expatriates.SE].  In my experience, household goods are exempt from duty when one is relocating, provided that the owner has had them for at least six months. 
Details may vary from one country to another.  If you're moving more than six months from now,  buy them today and keep the receipts.  If not, you may have to pay import duty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In most cases you'll be fine. Hot wheel cars are not particularly expensive (I assume) so even 10 shouldn't trigger any customs limit. If this is trip is your actual moving trip, anything you bring as "my household items" would also be exempted.

This being said customs regulation vary wildly around the world so it depends A LOT on what exact country you are entering (and partially also from where).

Comment: I am moving to Portugal from the US and the prices can range anywhere between $1 to around $30. The actual Hot Wheels models would be different and not exact duplicates. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score -1):

In a comment on an earlier answer you mention that you are moving to Portugal from the US.  The rules relating to the importation of household effects state:

> Household and personal effects may be imported into Portugal duty free, by the following persons, provided they do not own a fully furnished house in Portugal:
>
> - Portuguese citizens/citizens of other European Union countries residing in the U.S. for over 12 months who are transferring their residency to Portugal
> - Foreign nationals holding residency visas for Portugal.

Items such as clothes and personal items may be imported duty free; other items must have been in the use and possession of the person for over 1 year prior to their transfer to Portugal.

You must apply for Duty Free Status by submitting a list, in triplicate, of articles being imported, together with other documents, to the Consulate, which will issue a Baggage and a Residency Certificate (Certificado de Bagagem e Certificado de Residência), which must be presented to Customs in Portugal for clearance of the goods.

Source: https://washingtondc.embaixadaportugal.mne.gov.pt/en/consular-services/consular-services/importation-of-household-effects

Comment: The rules you are quoting are for unaccompanied baggage and apply to the bulk of the OP's collection, but the actual question was about bringing goods with him in his personal luggage.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I might have missed it but I don’t see any reference to unaccompanied baggage in the rules I linked to. But feel free to give a better answer.